# how to debug nativescript with visual studio code IDE?

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I am developing a app with nativescript.
I am using Visual Studio as IDE.
But I cannot debug in the IDE.
When I press F5 key...

> [NativeScript-Debug-Adapter] NativeScript CLI not found. Use 'nativescript.tnsPath' workspace setting to explicitly set the absolute path to the NativeScript CLI.

I don't solve the problem.
Please help me.
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you, that you haven't installed the Nativescript Cli. You can simply install it via `npm install -g nativescript`.

You can check the docs, how to install [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/quick-setup.html)

How the VisualStudio code integration works is described [here](https://www.nativescript.org/nativescript-for-visual-studio-code)